# Volume mixer for Ubuntu?

Tags: volume-control

I am looking for this but for Ubuntu . Does it exist?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

[Read about PulseAudio Volume Control 0.9.10](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/pavucontrol/)

[image: PulseAudio Volume Control 0.9.10]

Comment: It is a best sound, mate, enjoy! :)